# How to set sample rate when read frames from ALSA [FFMPEG C/C++]

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, microphone, alsa

I'm trying to get audio data from a microphone using **ALSA**. By default stream has a sampling rate of **44100 Hz**, but I need to get **8000 Hz**.

Trying to use **AVDictionary** options for **avformat_open_input** doesn't change anything.

The code is maximum simplified:

```
AVFormatContext *format_context = nullptr;
AVInputFormat   *input_format   = nullptr;

avdevice_register_all();

input_format = av_find_input_format("alsa");

AVDictionary* options = NULL;
av_dict_set(&options, "sample_rate", "8000", 0);

int res = avformat_open_input(&format_context, "hw:0", input_format, &options);

if(res < 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

res = avformat_find_stream_info(format_context, 0);

if(res < 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

av_dump_format(format_context, 0, "alsa", 0);
```

> Input #0, alsa, from 'alsa':   Duration: N/A, start:
> 1685994324.766645, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
> Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s

Is there probably some way to tell **ALSA** to output a lower sampling rate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with ALSA and nor do I have access to an ALSA device but I looked into the source code of `libavdevice/asla_dec.c`, `libavdevice/asla.c` `libavdevice/alsa.h`.

I came across these lines in `libavdevice/asla_dec.c`.

```
static const AVOption options[] = {
    { "sample_rate", "", offsetof(AlsaData, sample_rate), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64 = 48000}, 1, INT_MAX, AV_OPT_FLAG_DECODING_PARAM },
    { "channels",    "", offsetof(AlsaData, channels),    AV_OPT_TYPE_INT, {.i64 = 2},     1, INT_MAX, AV_OPT_FLAG_DECODING_PARAM },
    { NULL },
};
```

So, on my version of FFmpeg, the default sample_rate for `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near` is 48000.

On my MacOS machine, I find that the corresponding files `libavdevice/avfoundation.m` and `libavdevice/audiotoolbox.m` dont even give options for `sample_rate`(!) and I haven't been successfull in my attempts at changing the sample rate on `avfoundation`. Atleast `ALSA` seems to give you the option to set the `sample_rate` so you might actually be able to change the `sample_rate`.